# How to run celery worker in separate docker container

Tags: flask, docker-compose, celery

I have flask app and i want to add celery to do some background tasks.
Flask app is made with application factory if it does matter.

I read few guides but it is still unclear for me.

My app is structured like this:

```
-/app
--docker-compose.yml
--/server
---main.py
---server.ini(for wsgi)
---server.dockerfile
---/sweater
----__init__.py
----/celery
-----__init__.py
-----celery.dockerfile
-----tasks.py
```

now i presentmy code:
main.py

```
from sweater import create_app


flask_app = create_app()
celery_app = flask_app.extensions["celery"]
flask_app.app_context().push()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    flask_app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=8080)
```

/sweater/**init**.py

```
import redis

from flask import Flask
from flask_assets import Environment
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_login import LoginManager
from flask_user import UserManager

from sweater.celery import celery_init_app

db = SQLAlchemy()
login_manager = LoginManager()
server_ip='10.104.4.95:8080'
database = 'LOGISTICS_DEV'
red = redis.Redis(host='redis', port=6379, decode_responses=True)

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_pyfile("config.py")
    
    assets = Environment()
    assets.init_app(app)

    with app.app_context():
        db.init_app(app)
        
        from sweater.models import User
        user_manager = UserManager(app, db, User)
        user_manager.login_manager = login_manager

        @login_manager.user_loader
        def load_user(user_id):
            return User.query.get(user_id)
            
        celery_init_app(app)
        
        from sweater.routes import main
        app.register_blueprint(main)
        
        from sweater.auth import auth
        app.register_blueprint(auth)
        
        from sweater.arm_analyst import arm
        app.register_blueprint(arm)
        
        from sweater.dashboards.routes import create_dash_instance
        app = create_dash_instance(app, server_ip)
        
        from sweater.dashboards import dash_bp
        app.register_blueprint(dash_bp)
    return app
```

celery/**init**.py

```
from celery import Celery, Task

def celery_init_app(app) -> Celery:
    class FlaskTask(Task):
        def __call__(self, *args: object, **kwargs: object) -> object:
            with app.app_context():
                return self.run(*args, **kwargs)

    celery_app = Celery(app.name, task_cls=FlaskTask)
    celery_app.config_from_object(app.config["CELERY"])
    celery_app.set_default()
    app.extensions["celery"] = celery_app
    return celery_app
```

celery/tasks.py

```
from celery import shared_task

from time import sleep

@shared_task(ignore_result=False)
def add(x: int, y: int) -> int:
    sleep(5)
    return x + y
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.1'

volumes:
  base:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
       o: bind
       type: none
       device: /srv/samba/anonymous/docker_new/base
  root:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
       o: bind
       type: none
       device: /srv/samba/anonymous/docker_new
services:
  flask:
    build:
      dockerfile: server.Dockerfile
      context: ./server
    restart: always
    environment:
      TZ: Europe/Moscow
      FLASK_APP: flask_app
      APPLICATION_PORT: 8080
      CELERY_BROKER_URL: redis://redis:6379
      CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND: redis://redis:6379
    expose:
      - 8080
    volumes:
      - base:/base
    depends_on:
      - redis
  nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    build: ./nginx
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - flask
  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
  worker:
    build:
      context: ./server
      dockerfile: sweater/celery/celery.Dockerfile
    command: celery -A server.main celery_app worker --loglevel=info --concurrency=4
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - flask
    volumes:
      - root:/server
  monitor:
    build:
      context: ./server
      dockerfile: sweater/celery/celery.Dockerfile
    ports:
     - "5555:5555"
    command:  ['celery', 'flower', '-A', 'tasks']
    environment:
      CELERY_BROKER_URL: redis://redis:6379
      CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND: redis://redis:6379
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - worker
```

server.dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.9

WORKDIR /app

COPY . /app

RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r /app/requirements.txt

CMD ["uwsgi", "/app/server.ini"]
```

celery.dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.9

COPY ./sweater/celery /celery

RUN pip install -r /celery/requirements.txt

WORKDIR /server
```

I expexted that i need to create flask extansion and put celery there and then start a worker based on that extension.

I tried a lot of different settings, but i can't get the main idea of this. When i try to load celry app from flask extensions i get error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sweater'" and i think thats because my docker-compose command is trying to start another flask instance and create celery app for that flask instance. Am i right or i still don't understend how it works?